# Getting RouteData for actions with RouteAttribute

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, url-routing, asp.net-core-routing

I have a custom IRouter implementation, which looks in its basic form like this, for simplicity's sake I hardcoded some values:

```
public class MyRouter : IRouter
{
  private readonly IRouter router;
  public MyRouter (IRouter router)
  {
    this.router = router;
  }

  public async Task RouteAsync(RouteContext context)
  {
    context.RouteData.Values["controller"] = "Home";
    context.RouteData.Values["action"] = "Index";
    context.RouteData.Values["area"] = "";
    await router.RouteAsync(context);
  }
}
```

This works for a simple controller without a `[Route]` attribute defined:

```
public class HomeControlller
{
  public IActionResult Index()
  {
    return View();
  }
}
```

Again, this works correctly. Going to `/` will show the page.
However, as soon as I add `[Route]` attributes, I get a 404:

```
[Route("foo")]
public class HomeControlller
{
  [Route("bar")]
  public IActionResult Index()
  {
    return View();
  }
}
```

Now, if I go to `/foo/bar`, I will see the page. However, if I go to `/`, I get a 404.
How can I fix this? If I look at the RouteData values when going to `/foo/bar`, I still see the values `Home` and `Index` as values for controller and action, respectively.

Answer (score 1):

This is by design.

> Actions are either conventionally routed or attribute routed. Placing a route on the controller or the action makes it attribute routed. Actions that define attribute routes cannot be reached through the conventional routes and vice-versa. Any route attribute on the controller makes all actions in the controller attribute routed.

Reference: [Mixed routing: Attribute routing vs conventional routing](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/controllers/routing?view=aspnetcore-2.1#mixed-routing-attribute-routing-vs-conventional-routing).

For `Conventional router`, it is using `MvcRouteHandler`, and `Attribute route` will use `MvcAttributeRouteHandler`. When `Controller` or `Action` used with `Route[]`, it will not go to `Converntional router` when you request the specific method.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Yes I've read about it being by design. But there must be some way to make this work? I mean, could I still pass something to the RouteData to make this work? There must be some way to have a custom IRouter work with attribute routing!